# Efficient way to sum measurements / time series by given interval in php

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, summarization

I have a series of measurement data / time series in the same interval of 15 minutes. Furthermore, I have a given period (e.g. one day, current week, month, year, (...) and I need to summarize values by hour, day, month, (...).

E.g. summarize all values of the last month, by day.

My approach is to generate a temporary array with the needed interval per period in the first step. E.g. here in PHP (PHP is not that necessary, I would prefer Python or Javascript if it provides a faster method)

```
$this->tempArray = array(
'2014-10-01T00:00:00+0100' => array(),
'2014-10-02T00:00:00+0100' => array(),
'2014-10-03T00:00:00+0100' => array(),
'2014-10-04T00:00:00+0100' => array(),
(...)
'2014-10-31T00:00:00+0100' => array()
);
```

In the second step, I loop through each date/value pair (in this example 4*24*31, (96 per day)) and assign them to my temporary array. For each date, I override some values from the datetime object. In this example the hour and the minutes to match the keys in the temp array.

```
$insert = array(
    'datetime' => $datetime,
    'value' => $value
);

if ($interval == "d") {

    $this->tempArray[date('Y-m-d\T00:00:sO', $datetime)][] = $insert;
}
```

At the last step, I loop through the temp array and summarize each array. As the result, I receive an array with 31 new date/values pairs, summarized by each day. This works fine. However is there a faster way or more efficient way? It takes nearly 0.5 seconds with this approach for one month. (If someone is interested in the source code, I will add a gist). The data are stored within a mysql database with 15 mio entries.

// Edit: I think the best way is to group this with mysql.

My current SQL query to fetch data from one year:

```
SELECT
FROM_UNIXTIME(PointOfTime)) as `date`,
value
FROM data
WHERE EnergyMeterId="0ca64479-bddf-4b91-9e35-bf81f4bfa84c"
and PointOfTime >= unix_timestamp('2013-01-01T00:00:00')
and PointOfTime <= unix_timestamp('2013-12-31T23:45:00')
order by `date` asc;
```

Comment: as of your edit: Yes, the best way is to use mysql's `between` comparator and only fetch what you really need.

Comment: I do need all of the data. I fetch from -> to and need to group by and sum the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data lies in MySQL, then that is where I would implement my solution. It is trivial to use various MySQL date/time functions to aggregate this data. Let's take a simplistic example assuming a table structure like this:

```
id:  autoincrement primary key
your_datetime: datetime or timestamp field
the_data: the data items you are trying to summarize
```

A query to summarize by day (most recent first) would look like this:

```
SELECT
    DATE(your_datetime) as `day`,
    SUM(the_data) as `data_sum`
FROM table
GROUP BY `day`
ORDER BY `day` DESC
```

If you wanted to limit it by some period of time (last 7 days for example) you can simply add a where condition

```
SELECT
    DATE(your_datetime) as `day`,
    SUM(the_data) as `data_sum`
FROM table
WHERE your_datetime > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY `day`
ORDER BY `day` DESC
```

Here is another example where you specify a range of datetimes

```
SELECT
    DATE(your_datetime) as `day`,
    SUM(the_data) as `data_sum`
FROM table
WHERE your_datetime BETWEEN '2014-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-08-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY `day`
ORDER BY `day` DESC
```

Sum by hour:

```
SELECT
    DATE(your_datetime) as `day`,
    HOUR(your_datetime) as `hour`
    SUM(the_data) as `data_sum`
FROM table
WHERE your_datetime BETWEEN '2014-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-08-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY `day`, `hour`
ORDER BY `day` DESC, `hour` DESC
```

Sum by month:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(your_datetime) as `year`,
    MONTH(your_datetime) as `month`
    SUM(the_data) as `data_sum`
FROM table
GROUP BY `year`, `month`
ORDER BY `year` DESC, `month` DESC
```

Here is a reference to the MySQL Date/Time functions:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently trying to understand the date_sub and the group by commands. As I wrote in the question, my goal is to sum the values by a given interval in a daterange. I've added my sql query to fetch the data.

Comment: @wiesson I added another example to my answer where you query across a date range.  In looking at your query in your updated question, I notice that it seem you are using unix timestamp values in your field.  That is typically a bad idea in SQL.  You should favor the use of date, datetime, and timestamp fields when storing date/datetime values in MySQL. It prevents the needs to always convert to to/from unix timestamps when trying to query data. This means you will generally find it easier to leverage existing indexes on these fields.

Comment: @wiesson The GROUP BY functionality allows you to use aggregate functions in your query. IN my examples, you are summing up all data values for each date value. This eliminates the need to do this sort of summing in the application layer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint at the datetime field, I will check that for a new project. I don't really understand how to sum up by e.g. "hours" or by "month". Any further example?

Comment: @wiesson I added more examples on summing by hour (actually day and hour) and month (year and month).

Comment: A bit late now but, how would someone sum up to half hourly?

Comment: @josh Summing up by half-hours would be a little more complex as there is no "out of the box" way to aggregate on half-hour increments.  You would probably need to make a `CASE` statement in the `SELECT` to calculate the time into one of 48 half-hour slots.  The `CASE` being used in this case to determine if datetime falls within first half of an hour.  That statement may look like `(2*HOUR(your_datetime)) + (CASE MIN(your_datetime) WHEN >= 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS half_hour`.  This would yield values between 0 and 47. You would then refer to `half_hour` column for `GROUP`and `ORDER BY`